# Создание объекта из геометрических фигур

Tags: c#, объекты, visual-studio

Как можно нарисовать геометрическую фигуру (линию, квадрат, треугольник), потом преобразовать это в контрл или объект, чтобы можно было применять к нему ивенты, тултипы и прочее.

Думал сначала брать панельки, на них рисовать, но панели друг на друга накладываются и перекрывают друг друга.

Спасибо.

**Добавление:**
Возьмем к примеру CorelDraw или PhotoShop. В них можно создавать геометрические фигуры. После создания мы можем двигать их, менять размеры и выполнять прочие действия. Как можно сделать примерно такое-же в c#?

**Добавление 2:**
Используется Windows Forms. 
Да, требуется создавать контролы произвольной формы, но чтобы их фон не накладывался друг на друга.
Попробовал у батона сделать OpacityMask, но решарпер ругается, что такого нет. 
как сделать (пускай на примере баттона), чтобы у контрола был фон прозрачный, но был виден на нем рисунок.

и button1.BackColor = null - не катит.

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, сформулиуйте, пожалуйста, свой  вопрос грамотно - очень сложно понять, чего вы тут хотите

Comment: @DreamChild, да я сам не могу правильно сформулировать. Вот пример дописал. Прочтите. Если всё равно не ясно - попробую другими словами написать. Спасибо.

Comment: @Эмиль: А не покатит создать контролы с фоном = null (не Transparent)? Они должны по идее пропускать мышиные event'ы.

Comment: Я так понял, что выхотите создавать контролы произвольной формы?

Comment: @DreamChild: Угу, думаю, именно это автору и нужно. По идее, можно поиграться с OpacityMask.

Comment: а что вообще используется? winform, wpf? или чистая консолька, и рисовать будем на канвасе?

Comment: @VladD, @DreamChild, @Carma . Изменил шапку. Добавил объяснения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если хотите контролов с замысловатыми формами, то на WinForms это не так просто, как хотелось бы. Возможно, имеет смысл поковыряться в WinApi, к функциям которого придется обращаться из управляемого кода (об этом немного сказано [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread1577.html)). Есть там такая сущность, как регион, которая позволяет определить форму оконного компонента (в том числе и кнопок и всяких прочих контролов). Пару слов  об этом [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread127861.html) Как это все будет работать, честно говоря, не знаю, вероятно, придется танцевать с бубном и вызывать духов давно умерших предков, а также заботиться о корректном взаимодействии управляемого и не очень управляемого кода. (Если в двух словах, то все вышеописанное - не более, чем мое предположение, которое, вполне возможно, сработает..а вполне возможно что и нет)

А вот в  WPF с треугольными кнопочками все несколько проще - XAML позволяет такие штуки без особых извращений, насколько мне известно (ну и плюс поддержка аппаратного ускорения опять же). Более того, когда-то давно (года три назад)  мне в руки попал инструмент под названием Expression Blend - WYSIWYG-редактор XAML'a от Microsoft для создания интерфейсов приложений, в котором все эти круглые кнопки со всевозможными градиентами создаются без проблем. С тех пор прошло 3 года, и, думаю, создавать там все эти свистелки и перделки стало еще удобнее.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! 
Думаю, не зря на стене бубен висит. Вот и настало его время.
Как хорошо, что я еще не начал делать этот проект. Так что сразу начну в WPF'ке. Редактор обязательно посмотрю. Наверное он сильно мне пригодится. Получается с помощью ваших советов, можно создать примерно те же самые фигуры как в фотошопах?
Мне нужно сделать интерфейс примерно как в планах AutoCAD'a. То есть всякие линии, которые можно менять, приближать и тд.
Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Пока не буду принимать Ваш ответ. Вдруг еще люди зайдут и дельные советы дадут ;)